# How can I use react project in rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails-4, reactjs

I have no background about how to use js tools to convert those js scripts into Rails application.

How could I use this `react project` in ruby on Rails.

I have installed the react-rails gem,

Can I just simply clone the all the js scripts into `/vendor`, and use them as normal javascripts.

Is it a good practice to do so ?

Thanks

Comment: This should help you https://www.airpair.com/reactjs/posts/reactjs-a-guide-for-rails-developers

Answer (score 1):

I have a react starter app you can feel free to use. Will get you going quite nicely.

https://github.com/atomicjolt/react_starter_app